# Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'Django project name'. Heroku app deploy

Tags: python, django, heroku

I deployed my Django project with Heroku successfully but when I view my app I get an error page saying

> Application error An error occurred in the application and your page
> could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
> for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
>
> ```
> heroku logs --tail
> ```

when I put it in terminal I get this message

```
2021-03-16T08:50:34.762969+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-03-16T08:50:34.763493+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:55178 (4)
2021-03-16T08:50:34.763587+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-03-16T08:50:34.767113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2021-03-16T08:50:34.770278+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'ourUI'.
2021-03-16T08:50:34.770403+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-03-16T08:50:34.794976+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-03-16T08:50:34.799785+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'ourUI'.
2021-03-16T08:50:34.799990+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-03-16T08:50:34.904166+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-03-16T08:50:34.904279+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2021-03-16T08:50:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-16T08:50:39.982849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn ourUI`
2021-03-16T08:50:42.245442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
2021-03-16T08:50:42.310353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-16T08:50:42.140009+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-03-16T08:50:42.140941+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:31341 (4)
2021-03-16T08:50:42.141087+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-03-16T08:50:42.145144+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:42 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2021-03-16T08:50:42.148479+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'ourUI'.
2021-03-16T08:50:42.148628+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:42 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-03-16T08:50:42.182612+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-03-16T08:50:42.182707+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 08:50:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2021-03-16T08:51:10.997193+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hdpcapp.herokuapp.com request_id=ff5bdf78-e5b6-41cf-80e6-1bdf1d5f81f5 fwd="51.39.244.104" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

this is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn ourUI
```

requirement.txt

```
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.7
gunicorn==20.0.4
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

ourUI is my Django project

ourUI/setting.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'a-skd+xzh4&dka$6(wl5q*#7%b%q8a%aijy70cc#(5mw6+y25-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['hdpcapp.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'TheUI'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.whitenoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ourUI.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ourUI.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dtsticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

ourUI/wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ourUI.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm new to Django and heroku I hope I can get a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by editing my Procfile to

```
web: gunicorn ourUI.wsgi
```

and fixed w and n to W and N in (setting.py)

```
'whitenoise.middleware.whitenoiseMiddleware',
```

to

```
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
```